# Aligning horizontal recycler view below imageview using constraint layout

Tags: android

I am using below xml code for placing a horizontal RecyclerView  below ImageView
But My Recycler is not displaying and ImageView occupies entire space.
In Big size mobile design looks fine. But not able to acheive that for small mobile phones.

Horizontal RecyclerView consists of multiple images..it should be bottom of the screen...On clicking the image, I want to display it above horizontal RecyclerView.

I am using barrier for that issue but that does't solve my question.
Anybody please help me to find the solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constriantLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_current_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_photo_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/top_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/left_guideline"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/top_guideline"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/photo_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/barrier3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="39dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view_current_photo"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you show an image what you want and image what you get, plz. I think may be problem because of width and height or some constranint not correct.

Comment: @Hoàng Vũ Anh..not able to add image..sry...but I will explain in detail..I will edit my question

Answer (score 1):

Thank u all for ur answers,
I got a solution,
here it is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_current_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/image_view_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:contentDescription="@string/view_current_photo" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image_view_guideline"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_photo_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/top_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/left_guideline"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/top_guideline"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/photo_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image_view_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have try to modify your layout hope it help you, do not fix your image size.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constriantLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_current_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/top_guideline"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_photo_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/top_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/left_guideline" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/top_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/photo_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If it does't help you then post an image of your problem with at at least 2 different screensize.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about my answer but this is my code if i understand correctly your problem. RecyclerView scroll horizontall with each item is an image, when i click item, image will display, replace for image above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="vn.prdcv.dlreader.InputPasswordActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/panasonic"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/red"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```